# Hadoop with phoenix: how to write the phoenix table object to hdfs filesystem

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have a map reduce job, which reads from hbase table using phoenix. I want the output of this job is in HDFS and then feed to another map reduce job, where I will update in to HBASE table. This is what I have tried.

```
public class Job1Driver extends Configured implements Tool {
@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration jobConfiguration = super.getConf();
    final Job job1 = Job.getInstance(jobConfiguration, jobConfiguration.get("mapreduce.job.name"));
    final String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE IS_SUMMARY_RECORD=false";
    job1.setJarByClass(Job1Driver.class);
    PhoenixMapReduceUtil.setInputCluster(job1, jobConfiguration.get("HBASE_URL"));
    PhoenixMapReduceUtil.setInput(job1, Table1Writable.class, "TABLE1", selectQuery);
    if (jobConfiguration.get("IS_FROZEN_DATA_AVAILABLE").equals("True")) {
        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job1,new Path(args[0]),
                TextInputFormat.class, FrozenMapper.class);
    }
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job1,new Path(args[1]),
            PhoenixInputFormat.class,ActiveMapper.class);

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, new Path(args[2]));

    job1.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job1.setMapOutputValueClass(Table1Writable.class);

    job1.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
    job1.setOutputValueClass(Table1Writable.class);

    job1.setReducerClass(Job1Reducer.class);

    boolean st = job1.waitForCompletion(true);

    return st ? 0 : 1;

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();

    int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(conf, new Job1Driver(), args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
}
```

When I run this, I am getting something like this in output directory

```
hadoopDir.Table1Writable@5c8eee0f
```

Using Writable implementation, I can write to HDFS from the mapper out, but the same is not working for reducer out. Is there anything obvious I missed out?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using MapReduce because Phoenix queries do not scale?  We attempted to benchmark phoenix at Splice Machine (Open Source) and we could not get it to scale for large queries/updates.

I think you need to set

```
job.setOutputFormatClass()
```

Good luck...